Norm of a bounded operator to its range
Let $X$ be a Banach space and $V$ be a Banach space that is densely embedded in $X$. Suppose that $T:X\to X$ is a bounded linear operator such that $\text{range } T\subseteq V$.

Then $T:X\to V$ is a bounded linear operator. Is it true that $\|T\|_{X\to V}= \|T\|_{X\to X}$?

I could show by the closed graph theorem $T:X\to V$ is a bounded linear operator but I don't know how to comment on the norm although I suspect it should be true.

What norm are you putting on $V$ for there to be an issue? You can't apply the closed graph theorem if $V$ is not Banach, but with the norm of $X$ $V$ would be the whole of $X$ since it would be closed and dense. And if it is this norm, then you trivially have the desired equality.

@BrunoB I have edited my question, $V$ has its own norm. The embedding only gives that $|\cdot|_X \le |\cdot|_V$, which creates the issue.

There is no reason to expect the norm of the operator to be independent of the norm on $V$. There should be trivial counter-examples.

You can replace the norm on $V$ by say twice itself, then $\lVert\cdot\rVert_X\leq2\lVert\cdot\rVert_V$ still holds, but $\lVert T\rVert_{X\to V}$ changes if $T\ne0$

Perhaps you should ask whether $$|T|{X\to X}=|T|{X\to V}|J|_{V\to X}$$ where $J$ is the inclusion mapping. In this way multiplying the norm on $V$  by a constant does not affect the equality, if it holds. The inequality $\le$ is obvious. However the converse inequality may not hold even in the two dimensional case.
